# How do I make a popup <div> display only once per device?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, popup, popupwindow

So I've been trying to make a popup on the homepage of my website that gets displayed only the first time a device accesses my website, then, when it gets closed with a button it should not appear anymore.
To do this thing I tried thousands of ways and snippets but no one worked.

This is my code right now:

html

```
<div class="popup" id="popup">
    <!-- more elements for design purposes -->
    <button class="allCookies" onclick="closePopup()">Close popup</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.popup {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

JS

```
var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
var popupShown = localStorage.getItem("popupShown");

function closePopup() {
  popup.style.display = "none";
  localStorage.setItem("popupShown", "true");
}

if (popupShown === null || popupShown === "false") {
  popup.style.display = "block";
}
```

I wanted the popup to get displayed only the first time I open that html page, altough the popup keeps displaying every time the page gets reloaded.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Change the initial CSS of the popup to `display: none`. The rest of your logic will only then show it if `popupShown` is not `'true'`.

Comment: Sidenote: `"true"` and `"false"` can also be booleans if you parse the Storage value with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you set `display: block`, I think you want to change that to `display: none` or else the default will be, that it is always shown. Even if you don't set display to block in your javascript, it will already be so because of your CSS. Change that and it should be fine.

##### Sidenote:

You can parse `"false"` with `JSON.parse`:

```js
JSON.parse("false") // false
```

You can also use the `Boolean` constructor, though frowned upon:

```js
Boolean("false") // false
```

Comment: I changed the display property to none but now it doesn't show up at all, not even the first time the page gets loaded

Comment: I'm really sorry, your solution was right I made i typo, thank you